# How to Filter table by column in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I was trying to filter my columns in my django project template 
Currently I am able to search in the table and display the rows that have that that value 
But I would like to add a `dropdown` menu that would ask for a particular column value and then filter based on that value

currently my code is

views.py

```
def user_profile(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q','')
    custom = Customer.objects.all()
    if q: 
        custom1=custom.filter(name__contains=q)
        custom2=custom.filter(Product__contains=q)
        custom3=custom.filter(L3__contains=q)
        custom4=custom.filter(Server_Type__contains=q)
        custom5=custom.filter(Version__contains=q)
        custom6=custom.filter(Status__contains=q)
        custom7=custom.filter(PM__contains=q)
        custom8=custom.filter(CDM__contains=q)
        custom = custom1 | custom2 | custom3 | custom4 | custom5 | custom6 | 
                 custom7 | custom8
```

here name product l3 are my fields from my model that I would like to filter from

in my home.html

```
 <input type="text" class="text_field" id="search" placeholder="Search for..." required>
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="go()" value="go" id="submit">
```

my js.js

```
function go(){
    // alert("hellonikhar");
    var q = document.getElementById("search").value;

    window.open("/?q="+q,"_self");
}
```

I am storing the value entered in the textbox in var q and displaying the data but i would like to add a dropdown first which would choose the field and then q should filter based on only that column

Answer (score 1):

For adding a dynamic dropdown send column names from the backend.

```
<select name="columns">
    {% for column in columns %}
            <option value="{{column.name}}">Column {{column.id}}: {{column.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: it is giving me a dropdown but nothing is being viewed also how do i link it to my existing code so that once I choose a particular column from the dropdown menu and after that use my text field to view the resulting rows @TarunKumar

Comment: You need to pass column names from the view as "columns"  after selecting an option, pass the text in the textfield. Now in the backend use dropdown value as columnName, textfield value as columnValue.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dropdown with id as the column name and filter the objects by using that column value.

```
Customer.objects.filter(**{columnName:columnValue})
```

Comment: op asked about how create auto dropdown

Answer (score 0):

**Could you please try below query**

```
Customer.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=q)
                   |Q(Product__icontains=q)
                   |Q(L3__icontains=q)
                   |Q(Server_Type__icontains=q)
                   |Q(Version__icontains=q)
                   |Q(Status__icontains=q)
                   |Q(PM__icontains=q)
                   |Q(CDM__icontains=q)
                   )
```